# Why does Room observer add the same entity over and over again into the database?

Tags: java, android, json, android-room, observers

I retrieve `JSON` data that I have created and uploaded to the internet using `Retrofit`. I can successfully retrieve and display the data, but when I insert the data into `Room` database, only the very last `JSON` object is added, as many times as there are `JSON` objects it seems.

According to my `log` the `JSON` data is retrieved in whole in `Retrofits` `onResponse()` method - no problem there. But according to the `observer` method on the `getAllData()` from `Room` only the very last `JSON` object is added to `Room`. The observer is triggered, once for every `JSON` object, but every time, only the last `JSON` object is displayed. I have double checked the data base file using `Ridill SQLlte` and it confirms this:

[image]

My `Log` looks like this:

`//First observer shows nothing`

```
D/TAG: OBSERVED
```

`//JSON is retrieved, looks fine`

```
D/TAG: JSON GATHERED
D/TAG: ROOM NAME: Bob
D/TAG: ROOM DATE: 3/13/2015
D/TAG: ROOM FROM: 8:00
D/TAG: ROOM UNTIL: 13:00
D/TAG: ROOM NAME: Joe
D/TAG: ROOM DATE: 1/3/2015
D/TAG: ROOM FROM: 12.30
D/TAG: ROOM UNTIL: 13:00
D/TAG: ROOM NAME: Martin
D/TAG: ROOM DATE: 1/5/2015
D/TAG: ROOM FROM: 15.30
D/TAG: ROOM UNTIL: 16:00
```

`//Observer is set again, shows last of the JSON objects`

```
D/TAG: OBSERVED
D/TAG ROOM: MyRoomEntity{id=1, name='Martin', date='1/5/2015', from='15.30', until='16:00'}
```

`//Observer fires again, now having added the last JSON object a second time`

```
D/TAG: OBSERVED
D/TAG ROOM: MyRoomEntity{id=1, name='Martin', date='1/5/2015', from='15.30', until='16:00'}
D/TAG ROOM: MyRoomEntity{id=2, name='Martin', date='1/5/2015', from='15.30', until='16:00'}
```

`//Observer fires again, now adding the last object for a third time.`

```
D/TAG: OBSERVED
D/TAG ROOM: MyRoomEntity{id=1, name='Martin', date='1/5/2015', from='15.30', until='16:00'}
D/TAG ROOM: MyRoomEntity{id=2, name='Martin', date='1/5/2015', from='15.30', until='16:00'}
D/TAG ROOM: MyRoomEntity{id=3, name='Martin', date='1/5/2015', from='15.30', until='16:00'}
```

The `onResponse()` method looks like this:

```
public void onResponse(Call<List<RetrofitVariables>> call, Response<List<RetrofitVariables>> response) {
            List<RetrofitVariables> myResponse = response.body();
            MyRoomEntity myRoomEntity = new MyRoomEntity();

            Log.d( "TAG" , "JSON GATHERED" );

            if(myResponse != null) {
                MyRoomDatabase db = myViewModel.getRoomDatabase();

                    for(RetrofitVariables item: myResponse) {

                        Log.d( "TAG" , "name: " + item.getName());
                        Log.d( "TAG" , "from: " + item.getFrom());
                        Log.d( "TAG" , "until: " + item.getUntil());
                        Log.d( "TAG" , "Counter: " + counter);

                        myRoomEntity.setName( item.getName() );
                        myRoomEntity.setDate( item.getDate() );
                        myRoomEntity.setFrom( item.getFrom() );
                        myRoomEntity.setUntil( item.getUntil() );

                        //THESE LOGS SHOW CORRECT RESULT
                        Log.d( "TAG" , "ROOM NAME: " + myRoomEntity.getName());
                        Log.d( "TAG" , "ROOM DATE: " + myRoomEntity.getDate());
                        Log.d( "TAG" , "ROOM FROM: " + myRoomEntity.getFrom());
                        Log.d( "TAG" , "ROOM UNTIL: " + myRoomEntity.getUntil());


                        myViewModel.insertDataVM( myRoomEntity );

                    }
            }
        }
```

And my `observer` looks like this:

```
myViewModel.getAllDataVM().observe( this, new Observer<List<MyRoomEntity>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable List<MyRoomEntity> myRoomEntities) {
            //myAdapter.setList( myRoomEntities );

            Log.d("TAG", "OBSERVED");
            if(myRoomEntities != null) {
                for(MyRoomEntity item: myRoomEntities) {
                    Log.d("TAG ROOM ", "" + item.toString());
                }
            }
        }
    } );
```

Everything looks fine in the `onResponse()` method, so why arn't the data added properly into `Room`? How do I get all the `JSON` objects into `Room` and not just the last one? What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to reuse your room entity object. Move the

```
MyRoomEntity myRoomEntity = new MyRoomEntity();
```

To inside the populate loop

```
for(RetrofitVariables item: myResponse) {
    MyRoomEntity myRoomEntity = new MyRoomEntity();
    myRoomEntity.setName( item.getName() );
    myRoomEntity.setDate( item.getDate() );
    myRoomEntity.setFrom( item.getFrom() );
    myRoomEntity.setUntil( item.getUntil() );

    myViewModel.insertDataVM( myRoomEntity );
}
```

Comment: AWESOME! It worked like a charm! When I think about it, it certainly makes sense. Such a small thing though, lol. Big thanks @Roger, this saved me a lot of time and a headache :) Really appreciate you taking the time, thanks man! :)